# Code Syntax of ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have learned VB.Net with the help of some books and blogs like code project but I donot know even the basics of ASP.Net that I really want to learn.

Could you please advise me if there is any difference between the code syntax of vb.net and ASP.net or I can use the same syntax to build asp.net applications?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing your ASP.NET server-side code in VB, then it's standard VB.NET code just like you're accustomed to.  The two most popular languages for .NET are VB and C#, and you can use whichever you wish.  But the fact that you're using ASP.NET doesn't change the syntax or structure of either one of them.

Basically, ASP.NET is a web framework that you'd be using to build web applications written in your language of choice (in this case, VB.NET).  You'll want to know more about the framework, such as how to design your forms and make use of the web controls (and knowing HTML/CSS/JavaScript is a big help too).  But the overall syntax of the VB code doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net is not a language it is a framework.
vb.net is a language which used alongside asp.net to build websites/web applications.

So in a way yes there is a difference, but the difference is that they are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that VS provides a somewhat watered-down interface when using VB as opposed to C#. It's **really** worth your time to get familiar with C#.

[Microsoft's ASP.NET hub](http://www.asp.net/mvc) hub is a very comprehensive resource for tutorials. I'd recommend starting there, and coming back here when you have a specific question.

Comment: Why do you say that the VB interface is "watered-down"?

Comment: web.config transforms are hidden, IDE hides code-behind files by default, etc. I seem to remember some IDE commands that were hidden or completely disabled, but I don't remember specific examples at the moment. Then there's missing language features like multiline comments, static classes, `checked` sections (see wikipedia), strong(er) type enforcement, etc. Create a new vb web project, and a new c# web project, and compare them. Differences might not be that important to you.

Comment: I really am not trying to get into a language war but for the most part what you are describing is a difference between languages and doesn't have anything to do with VS. True, config transforms are hidden until the "Show All Files" button is pressed but that's just keeping in line with the VB paradigm of keeping things simple until complexity is needed. The same argument could be applied to C# hiding the `bin` and `obj` folders for the same reason. I often see C# people assuming that VB is the one that's doing something different because they assume that the C# is the "default way".

Comment: It's just an observation. Hiding complexity == reducing control, which isn't something I care for. But, you know what they say about opinions.

Comment: @David Lively: I don't agree with the claim that the interface for VB.NET is watered down. In theory, you can do anything in VB.NET that you can do in C#.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET is the technology, and you can choose which language you want to use with it. C# is the most widely used Microsoft languages, but you can develop ASP.NET applications in VB.NET too.

Use VB.NET to fimiliarize yourself with ASP.NET and get a handle on how it works. Eventually, it would be a good idea to learn C#, because it's the most widely used snytax in the world. Most modern languages are rooted in the C syntax, so by learning one of them you're learning all of them. It really is the biggest bang for your buck in terms of applicable experience.